# Does any programming language assign meaning to trailing spaces?

Tags: whitespace

There are a number of programming languages such as Python and F# that assign semantic meaning to leading spaces, so that if a line of code has leading spaces removed, it can break the whole program.

But what about trailing spaces?

Are there any programming languages that assign semantic meaning to spaces that come at the end of a line, just before the line feed or carriage return character?

(Let's assume I'm excluding languages that are nothing *but* space, e.g. [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).)

Comment: with only 37 users watching the whitespace tag, I doubt you will ever get an answer ...

Comment: There are places in C++ where it is significant, such as in multiline quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL is a language that's trailing whitespace sensitive, both in identifiers and multiline strings, and still used in many enterprise applications

```sql
-- Warning: horrifying, don't ever do this
CREATE TABLE [Table   
Name](
    [My 
        field] INT
);
SELECT * FROM [Table   
Name]; --Works;

SELECT [My 
        field] FROM [Table   
Name]; --Works

SELECT [My
        field] FROM [Table   
Name]; --Fails, lacks trailing space in field name

SELECT [My 
        field] FROM [Table  
Name]; --Fails, too few trailing spaces in table name
```

Comment: The fact that identifiers can have new lines scares me

Answer (score 2):

Markdown treats some trailing whitespace specially. When a line ends with two or more spaces, a line break `<br>` is inserted to break up a paragraph.

This rule is not well-known, so it may be triggered unintentionally and some linters disallow it by default ([MD009 no-trailing-spaces](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/Rules.md#md009)):

> This rule is triggered on any lines that end with unexpected whitespace. To fix this, remove the trailing space from the end of the line.
>
> Note: Trailing space is allowed in indented and fenced code blocks because some languages require it.
>
> The `br_spaces` parameter allows an exception to this rule for a specific number of trailing spaces, typically used to insert an explicit line break. The default value allows 2 spaces to indicate a hard break (`<br>` element).
>
> Note: You must set `br_spaces` to a value >= 2 for this parameter to take effect. Setting `br_spaces` to 1 behaves the same as 0, disallowing any trailing spaces.

As an example, these markdown paragraphs (middle dot represents space):

```markdown
Three···
trailing spaces

Two··
trailing spaces

One·
trailing space

No
trailing spaces

A··
mix
of··
spacing··
```

are rendered as such:

Three
trailing spaces

Two
trailing spaces

One
trailing space

No
trailing spaces

A
mix
of
spacing